# GCSE Volume of a Prism (Swimming pool question)

Tags: geometry

[image]

Hi, looking please for any help in answering part a) of the attached question.

My attempt was the following: 
Aim to use the formula for the volume of a prism.

Split the cross section into a 1.4m x 25m rectangle and then a trapezium with parallel sides of length 8m and 15m, base 1.6m. Multiply this by the length, 10m, to get 534m$^3$.

But how now does this help in answering the question? I feel like I may have missed something more obvious here. All help/solutions appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: $534$m$^3$ is correct. So if you know that there are 1000 litres in a cubic metre, you are all set. But I suppose not everybody knows that, so the question is flawed (unless it was part of your syllabus).

Comment: Not entirely sure if it was in the syllabus (will have to look over the spec again). Have solved it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need here is the volume of 1 litre of water. It so happens that $1l$ of water is $0.001m^3$.

If the pool takes $534m^3$ of water (I haven't checked your calculation), and $0.5m^3$ goes in per minute, I suppose that you can do the rest.

EDIT: You may wish to state your assumption about what the volume of $1l$ of water is.

Comment: There are 1000 liters in 1 cubic meter

Comment: Oh my. I've fixed that, now.

Comment: Got it! Thanks I have accepted the solution

Answer (score 0):

The cross sectional area is 53.4 m squares, so volume is 534 cubic meter. That equates to 534000000 cm cubed. That means it is equal to 534000 litres. Now 534000 L/ 500 L/ min=1068 minutes=17.8 hours.